# I'm not able to start Git in Android Studio 3.0.1

Tags: android, git, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

I have imported some of my old project in Android Studio 3.0.1.

Please check out attached screenshot,

[image]

And my **Version Control > Git** setting was look like below,

[image]

I also tried to clean and rebuild project but it's seems to be not worked, I got the same err.

I appreciate your help in advance. Thanks

Comment: Well, it says the path to your git executable is not valid. If you press the "..."-button next to Path to Git executable, is the git-executable in the folder that gets opened?

Comment: The path for git should be  valid, provide a valid path and check that by clicking **Test** ?

Comment: I have clicked Test button, and I got the error message

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found what is the issue.

Run the following command in-terminal,

```
sudo apt install git
```

And check git version,

```
git --version
```

Retest your git path from **Setting > Version Control > Git**

**Click on the Test button** and execute the git path.

Answer (score 2):

Your git path must be full path like below

```
    C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe
```

**Note-:** For checking git working or not by tap on Test button.

[image]

Comment: I am using ubuntu so please tell me path for it

Comment: copy the full path from where to install your git..like C drive or other

Comment: Okay I will do that